# Is it safe to use Apache Common IO library in an Android Application?

Tags: android, static-libraries, apache-commons

My android application need do some file/folder copy/delete/read/write operations. I found [Apache Common IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library has a lot of handy methods/classes for file operation. But I'm not sure whether it is safe to package Apache Common io as a static library into my application. It seems to me the methods/classes providered by apache common io library are very basic. Why Android didn't add it into android.jar at the very first? Is there any hidden/possible problem in using that library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many open source Android projects use it. You just add the jar file to the libs folder, as usual.

> But I'm not sure whether it is safe to package Apache Common io as a
>   static library into my application.

It is safe because how it can be not safe?

> Why Android didn't add it into android.jar at the very first?

Why should they have it added? You can add it yourself, if you want it.